# Method not supported error on parsing JSON.

Tags: android, json

i am trying the json parsing but when parse then is gives error 
httppost method is not supported by this url 
i put down my code here

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=restaurants&rsz=8&sll=-27.5595451,-48.6206452&radius=1000&output=json

```
SearchListActivity.java

 public class SearchlistActivity extends Activity {

    private static String url="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=restaurants&rsz=8&sll=-27.5595451,-48.6206452&radius=1000&output=json/";   private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";    private static final String TAG_RESPONSEDATA="responseData";    

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.e("json ----","urlll---->"+url);       
        //JSONArray results = null;       
         JSONArray responseData=null;
     // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JsonParserSearch jParser = new JsonParserSearch();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts

             responseData = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSEDATA);
             Log.e("jsonnn data","sfsssss00000-------->"+responseData);

            }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } }

>
```

> Jsonparsersearch.java
>
> > public class JsonParserSearch  {    static InputStream is = null;
> >         static JSONObject jObj = null;
> >         static String json = "";
>
> ```
> // constructor
> public JsonParserSearch() {
>
> }
>
> public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
>
>     // Making HTTP request
>     try {
>         // defaultHttpClient
>         DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
>         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
>
>         HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
>         HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
>         is = httpEntity.getContent();          
>
>     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>     try {
>
>         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
>                 is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>         String line = null;
>         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
>             sb.append(line + "\n");
>         }
>         is.close();
>         json = sb.toString();
>
>        Log.e("json object url","display"+json);
>
>
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
>     }
>
>     // try parse the string to a JSON object
>     try {
>         jObj = new JSONObject(json);
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>         Log.e("JSON Parser finaal", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
>     }
>
>     // return JSON String
>     return jObj;
>
> }      }
> ```

```
 >     > > lOGCAT ERROR
    >     > > 
    >     > > 11-09 12:23:17.700: E/json ----(481): urlll---->http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=restaurants&rsz=8&sll=-27.5595451,-48.6206452&radius=1000&output=json 11-09 12:23:18.260: E/json object url(481): display<HTML> 11-09
    >     > 12:23:18.260: E/json object url(481): <HEAD> 11-09 12:23:18.260:
    >     > E/json object url(481): <TITLE>HTTP method POST is not supported by
    >     > this URL</TITLE> 11-09 12:23:18.260: E/json object url(481): </HEAD>
    >     > 11-09 12:23:18.260: E/json object url(481): <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF"
    >     > TEXT="#000000"> 11-09 12:23:18.260: E/json object url(481): <H1>HTTP
    >     > method POST is not supported by this URL</H1> 11-09 12:23:18.260:
    >     > E/json object url(481): <H2>Error 405</H2> 11-09 12:23:18.260: E/json
    >     > object url(481): </BODY> 11-09 12:23:18.260: E/json object url(481):
    >     > </HTML> 11-09 12:23:18.260: E/JSON Parser finaal(481): Error parsing
    >     > data org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML> of type java.lang.String
    >     > cannot be converted to JSONObject 11-09 12:23:18.270:
    >     > D/AndroidRuntime(481): Shutting down VM 11-09 12:23:18.270:
    >     > W/dalvikvm(481): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
    >     > (group=0x4001d800) 11-09 12:23:18.290: E/AndroidRuntime(481): FATAL
    >     > EXCEPTION: main 11-09 12:23:18.290: E/AndroidRuntime(481):
    >     > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
    >     > ComponentInfo{com.example.ssss/com.example.ssss.SearchlistActivity}:
    >     > java.lang.NullPointerException 11-09 12:23:18.290:
    >     > E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at
    >     > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    >     > 11-09 12:23:18.290: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at
    >     > android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    >     > 11-09 12:23:18.290: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at
    >     > android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Get` request instead of `POST` request.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //make async request 
    new myAsynctask().execute();
}

//********************************************
//get json string
public String getJSONString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String urlString="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&q=restaurants&rsz=8&sll=-27.5595451,-48.6206452&radius=1000&output=json";

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlString);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Failed to download json response");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
//********************************************
private class myAsynctask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String jsonString=getJSONString();
        return jsonString;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonString);
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), jsonString);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to `POST` to a resource that only supports `GET`.

Try using an `HttpGet` rather than an `HttpPost`.

Answer (score 0):

jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url) uses POST method but you should use GET

Answer (score 0):

The error you receive comes from the server, as it is not supporting POST for that actual URLs.

It is good practice to check the HTTP status code before processing the result. Do this by calling `int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`. The status code 2XX means success (Codes listed [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)).

Another problem with your code is that though you are creating a POST request, all information is provided in the query parameters for the request. The POST part (body part) of the request is actually empty.

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("alma", new StringBody("beka", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
entity.addPart("apple", new StringBody("frog", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

This is an example of adding the parameters as POST parameters to the request...