# Method not supported on this platform

Tags: android, backbone.js, trigger.io

I'm using forge.prefs.get to fetch a cached user token and it works fine in iOs and web. I'm using backbone.js to render everything.
In Android, I get this error when trying to use the same call:

```
[DEBUG] Native call prefs.get with task.params: {"key":"user"}
[DEBUG] Native call notification.hideLoading with task.params: {}
[INFO] --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
[DEBUG] Returned: {"content":{"message":"Method not supported on this platform","type":"UNAVAILABLE","subtype":null},"callid":"4B01A334-2DC4-4511-A029-2C9D9B131D8C","status":"error"}
```

This is what I get when running the emulator. If I compile an APK and install it the code simply fails silently and the user is stuck on the login screen.

This is the code I use to fetch the info about the user:

```
     forge.prefs.get('user', function(user){ //success
      if(user === null){
        alert('USER not found');
        App.ViewManager.Login();
      }else{
        var u = JSON.parse(user);
        forge.logging.info(u);
        forge.logging.info(u.authentication_token);
        App.Utils.authToken = u.authentication_token;
        App.ViewManager.Companies();
      }
    })
```

And this is used to store the data:

```
forge.prefs.set('user', JSON.stringify(data), function(){},function(){});
```

Again, this works perfectly in iOS and web versions. Any ideas about why this happens?

I'm using android 4.4 on the emulator, Trigger toolkit version 2.1.3 and the prefs module is version 2.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method not supported error on parsing JSON.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303776/method-not-supported-error-on-parsing-json)

Answer (score 0):

When using `forge.prefs.set` or `forge.prefs.get`, you don't need to `stringify` or `parse` the data. The data is automatically stored as a JSON object, so try changing your code to just:

```
forge.prefs.set( 'user', data );
```

And remove the `JSON.parse(user);` line too.